# Drools---JUnit Testing - Drools Spring does not scan packages from source folders

Tags: spring, junit, drools, kie

I have a situation. I am testing bunch of .drl files using the kie-spring. The DRL files are found/scanned only when they are co-located in the src/test/resources folder and not in the src/main/resources/ folder.

I even moved the drl files to a separate jar project/file into a src/main/resources folder along with the kie-spring .xml files. Still no luck! The following is the warning I get!

2014-09-30 15:24:51,227 [AbstractKieModule] [main] WARN  No files found for KieBase MASTRT_KBase, searching folder \Users\mmadhavan.FACS_ORG\workspace\org.ncdb.facs.measures\target\test-classes

The following is my xml file!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:kie="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd

        http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd">


    <kie:kmodule id="kbase_inlist_op_test_rules">
        <kie:kbase name="MASTRT_KBase" packages="org.xxx.xxx.xxxxx.drl.cancer.MASTRT">
            <kie:ksession name="MASTRT_KSession" type="stateless" scope="prototype"/>
        </kie:kbase>
    </kie:kmodule>



    <bean id="kiePostProcessor" class="org.kie.spring.annotations.KModuleAnnotationPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved adding src/main/resources to testResources in pom.xml

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```